# Compiling Qt Tool out of Qt source tree

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to compile canbusutil found in qtserialbus/src/tools/canbusutil out of the Qt source tree. So i just copied the folder to another place and tried to compile. However, I end up with this error:

> Project ERROR: Project has no top-level .qmake.conf file.

So I had a look into the canbusutil.pro file:

```
QT = core serialbus

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    readtask.cpp \
    canbusutil.cpp \
    sigtermhandler.cpp

HEADERS += \
    readtask.h \
    canbusutil.h \
    sigtermhandler.h

load(qt_tool)
```

Removing the last line leaves me with different errors complaining that some conversions are not allowed or inherited methods not available. Building as part of the Qt sources works just fine. How do I have to adjust the *.pro file to get this to compile out of the Qt source tree.

Comment: Why not just compiling the whole `qtserialbus` submodule?

Comment: I know that I can build the qtserialbus submodule, however I hoped to be able to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the template, and make it a console project:

```
QT = serialbus
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    readtask.cpp \
    canbusutil.cpp \
    sigtermhandler.cpp

HEADERS += \
    readtask.h \
    canbusutil.h \
    sigtermhandler.h
```

Comment: I tried this, but this leaves me with the described errors like: conversion from 'QList<QByteArray>' to non-scalar type 'const QStringList' requested or error: 'const class QCanBusFrame' has no member named 'toString'.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to build `qttools\src\linguist\lrelease`
the tools are looking for `.qmake.conf` in the directory that contains the linguist directory.  So `qttools\src\.qmake.conf`

the contents of my `.qmake.conf` file is:

```
load(qt_build_config)
CONFIG += qt_example_installs
MODULE_VERSION = 5.8.0
```

**Disclaimer:**

My experience with this is on Windows so far.  Linux may have different default behavior, and I'm not yet sure which environment variable it would be related to.